# Search string and print from one line above to another search string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have file like below (temp1 file):

```
Basket1
10 Pens I have in Packet1
20 Books I have in Packet1
30 Red pens I have in Packet1
End here
Basket1
10 apples I have in Packet2
20 Mangos I have in Packet2
30 oranges I have in Packet2.
End here
```

I have written below code it will search start line and end line and prints between lines including start and end lines.

```
start_line = "Pens I have"
end_line = "End here"
print_lines = False
with open('temp1' , 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if (re.search(start_line, line)):
            print_lines = True
        if print_lines:
            temp = open("temp2", 'a')
            sys.stdout = temp
            print line
        if (re.search(end_line, line)):
            print_lines = False
            temp.close()
            sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Output I am getting:

```
10 Pens I have in Packet1
20 Books I have in Packet1
30 Red pens I have in Packet1
End here
```

I need help to print lines to file temp2 from above one line from start line to end line  . Below is the expected output to file temp2.

```
Basket1
10 Pens I have in Packet1
20 Books I have in Packet1
30 Red pens I have in Packet1
End here
```

Comment: please mention the problem/issue you are facing

Comment: Hi JkShaw, I need to print to file one above from the start line to end line. Now I am able to print only from start line to end line

Comment: you have already print lines to `temp2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to search your string, to use it for reading from and writing to file, you can do:

```
import re

with open('temp1' , 'r') as f1, open('temp2' , 'a') as f2:
    results = re.findall('\w+\n10 Pens I.*?End here', f1.read(), re.DOTALL)
    f2.writelines(results)
```

---

Example:

```
import re

s = '''Basket1
10 Pens I have in Packet1
20 Books I have in Packet1
30 Red pens I have in Packet1
End here
Basket1
10 apples I have in Packet2
20 Mangos I have in Packet2
30 oranges I have in Packet2.
End here'''

# use re.findall if you want to match multiple times
result = re.search('\w+\n10 Pens I.*?End here', s, re.DOTALL)

# only print(result) if using re.findall
print(result.group())

# output:

Basket1
10 Pens I have in Packet1
20 Books I have in Packet1
30 Red pens I have in Packet1
End here
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need `Basket1` to be printed, your `start_line` has to be `Basket1`, and as after first line you need `Pens I have` i have used it as 'mid_line',

```
import sys
import re

start_line = "Basket1"
mid_line = "Pens I have"
end_line = "End here"
print_lines = False

start_index = None
start_data = None
temp = None

with open('temp1' , 'r') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        line = line.strip()

        # Search for start_line, and store it's index and value
        if (re.search(start_line, line)):
            start_data = line
            start_index = index

        # If you find "Pens I have", and it's under start_line then store start_line
        if (re.search(mid_line, line)):
            if start_index + 1 == index:
                temp = open("temp2", 'a')
                sys.stdout = temp
                print start_data
                print_lines = True
        if print_lines:
            temp = open("temp2", 'a')
            sys.stdout = temp
            print line
        if (re.search(end_line, line)):
            print_lines = False
            if temp and hasattr(temp, 'read'):
                temp.close()
            sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Comment: I am getting  temp.close()
NameError: name 'temp' is not defined

Comment: Actually it would happen, when pattern won't be found. However updated the solution to handle that case too, see the updated solution.

Comment: Looping through an inerrable is inefficient compared to using methods of, for example, `list`, such as `index`. Also it would also be nice to see an example of how it works and the output.